# Populating arraylist to listBox in Vb Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

i am facing problem to populate value of a ArrayList to ListBox1.

```
With ListBox1

.ColumnCount = 1

.ColumnWidths = "250"

End With
```

Its giving error like object required near

> .ColumnCount = 1

Please help me out .

Comment: That would imply you don't have a listbox called ListBox1.

Comment: The .NET Listbox doesnt have a columncount property.  Not sure what VBA has to do with it

Comment: Looks like VBA code to me.  Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: Is your listbox from Form Control or ActiveX Control?

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a ActiveX Controls instead of Form Controls and Added Items like this.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
With ListBox1
    .ColumnCount = 1
    .ColumnWidths = 240
    .AddItem ("Item 1")
    .AddItem ("Item 2")
    .AddItem ("Item 3")
End With
End Sub
```